# Подсчет повторяющихся записей в data()

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте.

Добавляю с data(). Но не знаю, как можно подсчитать их

```
for (...) {
    $(".list#" + n).data({
        "title": "blabla",
        "fdfdfd": "dfdfd"
    });
}
```

Как можно подсчитать, сколько есть записей в data() где title=blabla?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

> > > ... сколько есть записей в data()...

Могу вас огорчить, но в [data()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85) не будет ни одной записи. Этот метод устанавливает/возвращает собственные переменные привязанные к объектам. А что пытаетесь сделать вы - я так и не понял.

P.S. Если надо подсчитать объекты, у которых установлена переменная с определенным значением, то [можно это делать так](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/e47Nd/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 0;
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].title == 'blabla') {
        count++;
    }
}
alert(count)
```